# Sorting an array of files for rename

Tags: c#, .net

I've recently written a small program to rename a bunch of files located in 6 directories. The program loops through each directory from a list and then renames each file in that directory using the File.Move method. The files are renamed to cart_buttons_1.png with the 1 incrementing by 1 each time.

```
public static int RenameFiles(DirectoryInfo d, StreamWriter sqlStreamWriter, 
                                       int incrementer, int category, int size)
{
    FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.png");

    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
    {
        File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, d.FullName + "cart_button_" + incrementer + ".png" );
        incrementer++;
    }

    return incrementer;
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is when I run the program more than once it runs fine up until it hits the folder containing the 100th record. The d.Getfiles method retrieves all the files with the 100s first, causing and IOException, because the file which it is trying to rename already exists in the folder. The workaround I've found for this is just to select all the records with 100 in the filename and renaming them all to 'z' or something so that it just batches them all together. Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix this. Possibly some way to sort the GetFiles to look at the others first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
var sorted = files.OrderBy(fi => fi.FullName).ToArray();
```

Note that the above will sort by the textual values, so you may want to change that to order by the numeric value:

```
files.OrderBy(fi => int.Parse(fi.Name.Split(new []{'_','.'})[2]))
```

The above assumes that splitting by `_` and `.` of a file name will result in an array with the third value being the numeric value.

Comment: if we know they're all in the same directory, wouldn't `(fi => fi.Name)` be slightly faster?

Comment: The array still returns with cart_buttons_100.png first. The folder starts at 85 and runs to 115. So when it sorts it it's still coming up: 100..115, 85, 86...

Comment: @NiallDuncan - Did you see me second example? Should do the trick.

Comment: Hadn't refreshed the page, so I didn't see that. Tried it out and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround would be to check if the destination name exists prior to attempting the copy. Since you have the `files` array already, you can construct your destination name and if File.Exists() returns true, skip that numerical value.

I would also handle the exception that is thrown by the File.Move (you want to test for Existance first to avoid unnecessary exception throwing) because the file-system is not frozen while your code works... so even testing for existance won't ensure it isn't created in the meantime.

Finally, I think that running this code again against the same directory is going to duplicate all of the files again... probably not what is intended. I would filter the source filenames and avoid copying those already matching your pattern.

Comment: The code also uses a StreamWriter to write a SQL statement to a text file within this loop, which is why I had to run it more than once. Took your advice and ran a check to see if the file already exists and only ran the File.Move if it didn't. Thanks a bunch!