# Sort files in ascending order

Tags: c#, winforms, list, fileinfo

I have  project that converts a pdf to tif image files. And the out put files are numbered in the form. file1, file2, file3.......file20.
When I do the code below to get the files, they are arranged in the list as shown below which is not correct. Any ideas how to go around this?

```
FileInfo[] finfos = di.GetFiles("*.*");

finfos[0]=file1

finfos[1]=file10

finfos[2]=file11

finfos[3]=file12

....
...................

finfos[4]=file19

finfos[5]=file2

finfos[6]=file20

finfos[7]=file3

finfos[7]=file4
```

Comment: will they always be called `file{number}` ? or is that just an example, and in reality they might be `my pics {number}` or `birthday {number} - Jim` ?

Comment: Search - there are several similar question on how to make comparator for such sort. Also if you simply name them "file0001" it would be much easier.

Comment: This one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373041/sorting-an-array-of-files-for-rename is very close to what you want.

Comment: Is there a possibility that some files don't have number in their filename?

Comment: DllImport StrCmpLogicalW from shlwapi.dll and use it to sort the finfos array.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am embedding an open source program that does the conversion and I am not sure I can change anything in it.

Comment: @MarcGravell that is just an example. the files are named mypic1.tif, mypic2.tif, mypic3.tif........mypic20.tif.

Comment: @IvanG  All the files have number. The problem infact is not the pdf conversion. Its the naming of the files. You can check it by naming about more than 10 files in a folder and then do di.GetFiles("*.*");
after file1, file10 will be next instead of file2

Answer (score 1):

If all of the files are named `mypic<number>.tif` and there are no files in directory that have different name format, try with this:

```
        FileInfo[] orderedFI = finfos
            .OrderBy(fi => 
                // This will convert string representation of a number into actual integer
                int.Parse(
                    // this will extract the number from the filename
                    Regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name), @"(\d+)").Groups[1].Value
                    ))
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried it also but I get an exception. But it might not be good for me after all because I am making a comic reader to also read image files in their natural order.
I think I am just missing something very important somewhere.
For example How do existing comic readers written in C# can be able to do this simply?

Comment: I see it works only when there are no other files in the directory. Since I want my program to collect all readable image files in a single list regardless of the name, Is there a way to split the file starting from the last 3 extension files as reference and apply your method?

Comment: If a mixture of filenames of different formats has to be sorted, for instance `11ab.tif`, `1ab.tif`, `2ab.tif` `abc.tif`, `ab1.tif`, `ab11.tif`, `ab2.tif`, how do you want to sort them?

Comment: +1. @electricalbah, it really up to you to filter out files you want to show. Some sort of filtering before sorting (like `.Where(fn => fn.Contains("someprefix"))` ) can easily do that.

Answer (score 0):

if they are created in order the do sort by date of created.

here is a solution to your problem by using List

```
class Program
{
    private static int CompareWithNumbers(FileInfo x, FileInfo y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
            {
                // If x is null and y is null, they're 
                // equal.  
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // If x is null and y is not null, y 
                // is greater.  
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If x is not null... 
            // 
            if (y == null)
            // ...and y is null, x is greater.
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {

                int retval = x.CreationTime<y.CreationTime?-1:1;
                return retval;          

            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("d:\\temp");
        List<FileInfo> finfos = new List<FileInfo>();
        finfos.AddRange(di.GetFiles("*"));
        finfos.Sort(CompareWithNumbers);

        //you can do what ever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link that prove that statement. (Obviously not the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) - "The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed" )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  Can you please rename some files from 1 to say 12?
After file1 is fetched file10 will be next instead of file2

Comment: i added a solution with List<FileInfo>

Comment: I doubt this is solution to the problem - it sorts by CreationTime (which actually does not need comarer at all - `.OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime)`) when OP asks for ordering on number embedded in file name.

Comment: My first comment is likely wrong as I read "the do sort" as "their are sorted" when it probably should be read as "than you can sort". Will hopefully remove this and first comment at some points.

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeros may be a solution for you. It's not clear from your description if you control the code that generates the files.
If not you can use a method to match file1,... file9 (i.e. regex or filename length) and rename them.
If you control the code then use a formatter to convert the number to string with leading zeros (ie for 2 digit numbers {0:00}).

EDIT:

To get a direction play with the following draft sample:

Assume that you have on the execution directory the files: file1.txt, file2.txt, file10.txt, and file20.txt

```
foreach (string fn in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(".", "file*.*"))
  if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(fn, @"file\d.txt"))
    System.IO.File.Move(fn, fn.Replace("file", "file0"));
```

The above piece of code will rename file1.txt to file01.txt and file2.txt to file02.txt.

Comment: I am not in control of the file that generates the images files, apart from that I want to read comic image files as well that have this same numbering.   I think your second option might be helpful. But I am a beginner and can you provide me with some sample?